# Problem 9, chapter 15 of Spivak book

Tags: calculus, integration

Well, I want to solve the exercise that says

Show that if $f$ is continuous, then $$\int\limits_0^x f(u)(x-u)du=\int\limits_0^x \left(\int\limits_0^uf(t)dt\right)du$$

Try to consider the following

$F(x)=\int\limits_0^xf(u)(x-u)du=\int\limits_0^xxf(u)d(u)-\int\limits_0^xuf(u)du$

then

$F'(x)=(xf(x)+\int\limits_0^xf(u)d(u))-xf(x)=\int\limits_0^xf(u)du=f(x)$

At this point, it is not clear to me how to conclude equality. Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $F(0)=0$ and $F'(u)=\int_0^uf(t)\,\mathrm dt$, you have\begin{align}F(x)&=F(x)-F(0)\\&=\int_0^xF'(u)\,\mathrm du\\&=\int_0^x\int_0^uf(t)\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm du.\end{align}

Comment: why do you have this? $F(x)-F(0)=\int_0^xF'(u)$ can you give me a hand? i'd appreciate it

Comment: By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if $F'$ is continuous, then$$\int_a^bF'(u)\,\mathrm du=F(b)-F(a).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's integrate by parts, considering that $ y\mapsto\int_{0}^{y}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t} $ is an antiderivative of $ f $, and that the derivative of $ y\mapsto x-y $ is $ -1 $, we have : \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{x}{\left(x-y\right)f\left(y\right)\mathrm{d}y}&=\left[\left(x-y\right)\int_{0}^{y}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\right]_{0}^{x}+\int_{0}^{x}{\int_{0}^{y}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &=\int_{0}^{x}{\int_{0}^{y}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}y}\end{aligned}